# How to reopen an android activity to find it as it was?

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

I've tried to do research on activity lifecycles but I don't seem to be able to find what I'm looking for (or I just don't understand it.) I've built a timer app with the actual timer not as the main activity, but a separate activity that you can get to from the home screen. When I start the timer and press back to go back to the homescreen, the timer is still active. I know this, because the app vibrates my phone when the timer runs out. However, if I go back to the homescreen and then press the button to go to the timer activity, the screen looks as if the timer isn't running. it's as if a new activity is created, as if I could have multiple timers run at the same time.

here's the `onCreate()` code for my `TimerActivity.class`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
    createComponents();
    setFont();
    setTimes();
    buttonFunction();
```

My guess is that the `setTimes()` function might be resetting the screen to look as if the timer isn't running, but I don't know how to fix it. It's just a hunch, anyway. Here's the code for that:

```
public void setTimes() {


    min1s = String.format("%02d", min1);
    sec1s = String.format("%02d", sec1);
    min2s = String.format("%02d", min2);
    sec2s = String.format("%02d", sec2);
    min3s = String.format("%02d", min3);
    sec3s = String.format("%02d", sec3);
    min4s = String.format("%02d", min4);
    sec4s = String.format("%02d", sec4);
    min5s = String.format("%02d", min5);
    sec5s = String.format("%02d", sec5);
    min6s = String.format("%02d", min6);
    sec6s = String.format("%02d", sec6);

    study1textM.setText(min1s);
    break1textM.setText(min2s);
    study2textM.setText(min3s);
    study1textS.setText(sec1s);
    break1textS.setText(sec2s);
    study2textS.setText(sec3s);

    break2textM.setText(min4s);
    study3textM.setText(min5s);
    break3textM.setText(min6s);
    break2textS.setText(sec4s);
    study3textS.setText(sec5s);
    break3textS.setText(sec6s);
}

min1-6 and sec1-6 are just ints with the default timer values, and the `textM` and `textS` are just EditTexts.
```

As you can probably tell, I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your specific data by implementing onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) in your activity. And restore saved data during onCreate() if 'savedInstanceState' you receive is'n null.

See docs for details http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

Comment: I'm gonna start looking at that now. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Currently reading about overriding onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState). It looks like if the timer is running and is at 19:30, and I save the instance state and come back in two minutes, it would still read as 19:30. I want to return to the activity while the timer has been running in the background to find it where it should be.

Comment: The interesting thing is that if i don't finish the activity and recreate it, but rather press home, when i come back it's as it should be.